# c++ hpp file was included in many files and compiler report "LNK4006"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I wrote a Semaphore.hpp where I declare an class `Semaphore`and define the member function.I have add "#pragma once" at the head of hpp file which means this file will be compiled only once. But the compiler reports link warning.I don't why, thanks!

```
2>Generating Code...
2>IPC_shared_memory.obj : warning LNK4006: "public: void __cdecl Semaphore::wait(void)" (?wait@Semaphore@@QEAAXXZ) already defined in IPC_socket.obj; second definition ignored
2>IPC_shared_memory.obj : warning LNK4006: "public: void __cdecl Semaphore::notify(void)" (?notify@Semaphore@@QEAAXXZ) already defined in IPC_socket.obj; second definition ignored
2>IPC_shared_memory.obj : warning LNK4006: "public: bool __cdecl Semaphore::tryWait(void)" (?tryWait@Semaphore@@QEAA_NXZ) already defined in IPC_socket.obj; second definition ignored
2>IPC_shared_memory.obj : warning LNK4006: "public: bool __cdecl Semaphore::waitFor(long)" (?waitFor@Semaphore@@QEAA_NJ@Z) already defined in IPC_socket.obj; second definition ignored
2>IPC_shared_memory.obj : warning LNK4006: "public: int __cdecl Semaphore::getValue(void)" (?getValue@Semaphore@@QEAAHXZ) already defined in IPC_socket.obj; second definition ignored
2>IPC_shared_memory.obj : warning LNK4006: "public: void __cdecl Semaphore::resetValue(int)" (?resetValue@Semaphore@@QEAAXH@Z) already defined in IPC_socket.obj; second definition ignored
```

Comment: `#pragma once` only applies to `#include`s within the *same run of the compiler*. Besides that, any function definitions in headers should be marked inline to avoid duplicate symbols.

Comment: You can force the binary creation by using linker flag `/FORCE:MULTIPLE`. Explained in this [msdn link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/70abkas3(v=vs.140))